# Analyzing touch events in a child view and let the parent handle them if condition not satisfied

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-controls, touch-event

I have extended a FrameLayout and overriden the **onInterceptTouchEvent()** and **onTouchEvent()**. This custom Framelayout will be the root layout of my ListView rows.

My requirement is that, if I tap on a row in the ListView, the onItemClickListener should be called, if I scroll (up/down) the list scrolls as usual. However if I scroll (left/right) or swipe (left/right), the custom FrameLayout should take some action based upon which row I perform the action on.

My idea was that, I would override **onInterceptTouchEvent**, monitor the events and if I see that ACTION_MOVE has been called enough to make it a scroll/swipe then I take control and do the task. If it's a tap or some other gesture then let the default flow occur.

The problem I face now is that if my framelayout does not contain any touchable child, then I receive no calls post ACTION_DOWN. And if I receive the ACTION_DOWN in my **onTouchEvent()** so as to analyze the kind of gesture, then I have no control left to let the default flow occur if I calculate and find that the action was actually just a tap/vertical scroll.

Is there some way in which a child can get hold of the events (ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE) and if a condition satisfies then perform an action or else let the parent handle these same events?

Is there some other approach that I can take to satisfy this requirement?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm running into the same issue.